# Android/Eclipse - saving button error

Tags: android, eclipse, button, save

I have some problems with the "setOnClickListener(onSave)” and “View.OnClickListener”

Below is my code:

```
package apt.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LunchList extends Activity {
Restaurant r = new Restaurant ();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//save button
//be notified when the button is clicked
Button save =(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

save.setOnClickListener(onSave){
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener();
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);

    r.setName(name.getText().toString());
    r.setAdress(address.getText().toString());
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

for save.setOnClickListener(onSave) I get the error save.setOnClickListener(onSave) and for View.OnClickListener I get the error Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener.

I looked on this website and googled for this problem put I didn’t find a solution. I hope you guys can help me out.

Greets.

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolon after

```
private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener();
```

and write onClick(View v) inside anonomous constructor of onClickListener
or else change your code with below code.

```
private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener(
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);

    r.setName(name.getText().toString());
    r.setAdress(address.getText().toString());
});
Button save =(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
```

Comment: removing the semicolon fixes the view.OnClickListener issue. save.setOnClickListener(onSave){ remains to have an error.

Comment: change it to save.setOnClickListener(onSave); it doesn't require another block.

Comment: Fixes current error. But new error pops up under onSave -> Syntax error on token "onSave", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Comment: first initialize the OnClickListener and then set it to button. you are doing the reverse way.

Comment: I changed it to private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
      
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Button save =(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
     
     save.setOnClickListener(onSave); 
     
     EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
     EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);

It gives me now the warning that onSave is not used. Other errors dissapeared.

Comment: Hey, I edited my Code in the answer, you just copy that and paste inside the oncreate() and remove all your code.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
         start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            mainactivity();

        }
    });
```